# How to write sql query to select other if not found

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have records in table which has values in `destinationcountryid` field like 638,101, and -1. -1 is default value if nothing matches select query should return this record.

I wrote below sql query.

```
SELECT
  externalid
FROM
  mLookup.Addon_Spec_Tbl
WHERE
  productid = 30046 AND keyid = 2 AND countryid = 638 AND clientid = 10018 AND subkeyid = 4 AND destinationcountryid IN(302,
  -1)
ORDER BY
  id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Here I am not getting correct result.
My table schema is as below

```
CREATE TABLE spec_tbl(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  productid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  keyid INTEGER,
  subkeyid INTEGER,
  externalid CHARACTER VARYING(100),
  countryid INTEGER,
  destinationcountryid INTEGER,
  originid INTEGER,
  destinationid INTEGER,
  clientid INTEGER,
  categoryid INTEGER,
  created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone DEFAULT NOW(), 
  modified TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone DEFAULT NOW(), 
  enabled BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE, 
  CONSTRAINT spec_tbl_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Sample insert

```
INSERT INTO spec_tbl(
productid, keyid, subkeyid, externalid, countryid, destinationcountryid, originid, destinationid, clientid, categoryid, remarks)
VALUES
(30046, 2, 4   , 'ABC', 638, 603, NULL, NULL, 10018, 25,'International Round Trip(include India) One Way Trip'),
(30046, 2, 4   , 'LMP', 638, 302, NULL, NULL, 10018, 25,'International Round Trip(include Bangladesh) One Way Trip'),
(30046, 2, 4   , 'KJP', 638, 208, NULL, NULL, 10018, 25,'International Round Trip(include Cuba) One Way Trip')
(30046, 2, 4   , 'XYZ', 638, -1, NULL, NULL, 10018, 25,'International Round Trip'),
;
```

I am getting response but its returning record of destinationcountryid = -1.
but there is match present destinationcountryid = 302. I expect this into result.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking here.  If that query returns no records, and you're 100% certain that the logic be correct, then your data is the problem.  In any case, if you could rephrase your question by showing us sample data along with the expected output, that might help to clarify things.

Comment: Added sample record

Comment: By the limit clause I am guessing it is MySQL. Please be specific with the tags.

Comment: @PacoDePaco Postgres also has a `LIMIT`.

Comment: its in postgres, but this doesn't matter.

Comment: sorry, I'm a sql server guy

Comment: sql is same for all

Comment: We're going around in circles and I won't comment further until you _edit_ your question with the actual query you are running.

Comment: i have added all the queries in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you want is that if your current query successfully matches a record, then return the external id value of that record, otherwise return -1.  We can simulate this behavior by placing your query into a CTE.  Then, do a union of that query with a query returning -1 which only fires if the CTE returns no records.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT externalid
    FROM Spec_Tbl
    WHERE
        productid = 30046 AND
        keyid = 2 AND
        countryid = 638 AND
        clientid = 10018 AND
        subkeyid = 4 AND
        destinationcountryid = 302
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
)

SELECT externalid::int
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT -1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) = 0;
```

Comment: How to write as final query to this?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I copies above and executed in sql prompts. it gives error. ERROR:  UNION types character varying and integer cannot be matched. LINE 18: SELECT -1

Comment: Is `externalid` a character column?  It probably should not be.  Try my updated answer.

Comment: there is can be more than one column in select result.

Comment: No, not according to the query you posted.  You select _one_ column and `LIMIT 1` limits the result set to a single record.

Comment: limit should be 1, but there can be more than one column possible. externaid field is character type.